# How straightforward would it be to statically link an app to my own customized obj-c runtime?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, objective-c-runtime

I've been playing with the runtime and came up with an alternative to objc_allocateClassPair / objc_registerClassPair that produces anonymous classes.

Anonymous classes would be extremely handy for something I'm working on, but I'm worried that since they depend on the way that the runtime's opaque data types are implemented (and to my knowledge, the runtime is a shared library that may change the layout of these types between OS versions) it'd be asking for trouble.

More generally, the fact that the runtime is open source seems to open up a certain potential for creativity with the language...

How straightforward would it be to statically link to my modified runtime instead of the shared one? Would I have to mess with the compiler, or would it be more like linking to any other library.

Also interested in how this might affect App Store approval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Likely, it is ultimately more trouble than it is worth.   Certainly, you don't want to replace the runtime being used by the system frameworks.  Not only is it likely impossible (or certainly extremely hard), it is also quite likely going to make your app unbearably slow as there are numerous optimizations that can only be done at the system level.

Doing so would likely require significant compiler and linker shenanigans.  You are also going to run into issues of boundaries;  is a call site a call into your code or a call into the system (if you were to try to run two runtimes in parallel -- which is likely impossible).

You are definitely correct in the assessment that relying upon the layout of the metadata in the current runtime is a no-go.  All of the metadata was put behind APIs in the Obj-C 2.0 transition specifically to allow for the metadata to change significantly without breaking [properly written] applications.

If you really want a new/different runtime model for some subset of functionality in your class, it is best to isolate that from the system runtime as much as possible.   A new root class might be interesting, but any intermingling with framework classes is likely to be rife with fragility.

Comment: I guess the issue with system frameworks kills it. For all I know, Foundation might make assumptions about the version of the runtime it's run with and will break horrifically if, say, 10.7's framework is linked against a branch of the runtime from 10.6...